# Postgres.app fails to start

Tags: macos, postgresql, heroku, osx-lion, heroku-postgres

I am trying to run Postgres.app on my OS X 10.7.5. When I run Postgres.app I get this error:
[image: Postgres.app startup error]

The report is as follows:

```
Process:         com.heroku.postgres-service [934]
Path:            /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/XPCServices/com.heroku.postgres-service.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.heroku.postgres-service
Identifier:      com.heroku.postgres-service
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  com.heroku.postgres-service [931]

Date/Time:       2013-09-03 11:55:56.466 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63b)
Report Version:  9

Anonymous UUID:                      3CF7D445-3EBA-4D64-AA7E-ADE812E0F3F0

Crashed Thread:  Unknown

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00007fff5fc01028

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000055  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x0000000000000000
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff5fc01028  rfl: 0x0000000000010203  cr2: 0x00007fff5fc01028
Logical CPU: 2

Binary images description not available


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 2066
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 0
```

I don't have any other installation of Postgres running. Confirmed this by running:

```
ps aux | grep -i post
```

The Postgres.app menu icon shows 
[image: Postgres.app menu]

There's no application running on port 5432 either. Confirmed this by running

```
netstat | grep 5432
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked around this by installing Postgres.app v9.2.2 from http://postgres-app.s3.amazonaws.com/PostgresApp-9-2-2-0.zip

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug in PostgresApp 9.2.4.3 that makes in crash on Lion. You can find previous releases on github: https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/releases

(I don't usually check Stackoverflow for Postgresapp bug reports, if possible it would be best to report issues on github: https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues?state=open)

Comment: Also, the bug is fixed in 9.2.4.4 and in 9.3.0.0